# Mono navigation

Tags: xamarin, navigation, mono, xamarin.android

I just started out with mono and I've already gotten problems. I'm used to play with c# code and was told that mono would be easy for me, but no no. I simply want to start a new activity and close the one i just were using. I checked out some mono API examples, but they are simply too complicated for this task. It has to be some easier way of doing it. This is my first activity class:

```
[Activity(Label = "CryptotoDroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
    EditText inputpassword;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        inputpassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.beforetext);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            if (inputpassword.Text == "Moo")
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(ActivityContacts));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is what i tried, but the program crashes. I Simply want to make the program to start a new activity when the password is "moo".
The activity I want to start is:

```
    [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
    public class ActivityContacts : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            var contactgrid = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);

        }
    }
```

Later on, i would also like to fill out my gridview with all contacts in the phone, but that belongs to another topic.

Comment: when you say the program crashes... when does it crash - before it starts? during the onCreate method? when you hit the button?

Comment: For info on how to use StackOverflow, it's worth looking through http://stackoverflow.com/faq - in particular, please try not to accept answers that aren't correct - people can upvote them if they are helpful, but don't mark them with a 'tick' unless they are the answer. When you've got a few more points you'll be able to upvote answers too :) And maybe you can already add an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to set both activities' content views to the Main layout?

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

`public void setContentView (View view)`

*Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a complex view hierarchy. When calling this method, the layout parameters of the specified view are ignored. Both the width and the height of the view are set by default to `MATCH_PARENT`. To use your own layout parameters, invoke `setContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)` instead.*

Comment: No, I didn't mean to set both content view's to main layout, when I fixed it, the program ran fine, even got to a prototype stage of the application! How stupid was I?:D My comfort lies in that c# isn't monodroid:D

Answer (score 0):

For starting with MonoDroid, I recommend:

- getting hold of one of the excellent books out there (Wally, Greg, Chris or others will be along with suggestions - I've personally yet to see a bad one so won't give a recommendation!)
- try watching a couple of the Xaminar's on youTube -http://www.yourepeat.com/g/Xaminar
- try building the Xamarin sample programs and then try adapting them - it's sometimes easier to adjust working programs than it is to start new ones (sometimes!)
- try building new things just as you have above.

When you hit problems - as we all do - then please do ask questions here or on the Xamarin forums - people will help.

However, when you hit a crash or exception, please try:

1. Give us as much info as you can about the crash/exception - including there are some ways to get extra debug logs off of a phone or emulator - http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Deployment,_Testing,_and_Metrics/Android_Debug_Log - these logs often contain important text which will help us help you diagnose the crash
2. If you are running under the VS2010, VS2012 or MonoDevelop debugging tools, try adding extra Console.WriteLine statements and/or use breakpoints - this can help you and us work out which line is causing the crash - or if the crash is occurring somewhere in setup before the code even runs.

Speaking personally, I believe Mono for Android does help experience C# devs exploit their skills on Android - but there's still new things to learn, and there are still embedded development frustrations to tackle and overcome (like these sort of crashes)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, although it didn't help me at all, I solved it by myself. Thanks, once again